# Where to put page-specific JavaScript code?

Tags: javascript, standards, code-organization

Say I have two pages: `Page1.html`, and `Page2.html`. Both pages need:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Init();
});
```

Only Page1.html needs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitPage1();
});
```

Only Page2.html needs:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    InitPage2();
});
```

**What is the best practice for structuring the JavaScript files, considering overhead for additional requests vs. overhead for executing irrelevant code?**

**Option 1:**

I can make 3 JavaScript files, one that's referenced on both pages, one that's referenced only on `Page1.html`, and one that's referenced only on `Page2.html`.

The advantage is that each page is not running irrelevant code in `$(document).ready()`.

The disadvantage is that `Page1.html` and `Page2.html` will need to make 2 requests for JavaScript files, one for the shared file, and another for the page specific file, and the extra request will add overhead.

**Option 2:**

I can make 1 JavaScript file that's referenced on both pages that contains all the code for both pages.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    Init();
    InitPage1();
    InitPage2();
});
```

The advantage is that each page will only make 1 JavaScript file request, which reduces overhead.

The disadvantage is that unnecessary code in `$(document).ready()` is now being run for both pages.

**Option 3?:**

Is there a better option I'm not considering?

**Final Considerations:**

The main concern here is what will be ideal when dozens of pages need their own JavaScript code that will not be shared anywhere else?

Requests for individual files can be expensive. I'm seeing 100-450ms for each JavaScript file request for one of my websites, with virtually all of the time going towards "waiting" rather than "downloading," which means the bottleneck is at the request itself, and not the file size, i.e., if 5 individual JS files each take 200ms to load (1sec total), if they were all combined into 1 file, the increased file size would be virtually irrelevant and the request should only take about 200ms total (maybe very slightly higher, 50ms or less, to load the additional data).

So my hypothesis would be that combining everything into 1 file would be ideal, but it just seems extremely sloppy to have irrelevant code running on every page, especially if for some reason the irrelevant code had a high execution time. What is best practice for handling this?

Comment: What does this have to do with c# or asp.net? BTW, `$(document).ready(function ()` should be written as `$(function()`

Comment: And you should also read into Bundling which aims to solve the problem of the limit of maximum concurrent requests

Answer (score 0):

Your second code wont work as *InitPage2 may not be a function*. But thats what if elses are for:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
Init();
if(InitPage1) InitPage1();
if(InitPage2) InitPage2();
});
```

However, this code is not really DRY. So you might create sth like a core.js, where you do some general stuff that is needed everywhere, then you can call those functions in your extensions:

```
var onready=[];
$(document).ready(function () {
 onready.forEach(func=>func());
 onready={push:func=>func()};
});
```

In your extensions:

```
onready.push(_=>alert("Wohoo!"));
```